# How can I create 2 small circles on the left and right hand side of another circle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I create 2 small circles on the left and right hand side of another circle, equally spaced horizontally and vertically just like two ears on the side of a face?

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS3.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the alignment using Photoshop´s alignment tool.

1) Draw  your 3 circles.

2) Use a guide to horizontally place the circles one next to the other.

3) Select the 3 circles with the move tool (easier if you have them in separate layers) and you will see the position controllers in the top bar:

[image]

Just click on the desired one (in your case, the second button), and it will align your circles vertically.